# SherlockMapActivity and onTap Event

Tags: android-mapview, actionbarsherlock

I'm using this plugin: 
https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock-Plugin-Maps/downloads

To have MapViewActivity inside ABS.

My probleme is I want to detect the onTap event on the map, not on the overlay and the onTap method doens't seems to be present in the SherlockMapActivity.class

How to do it ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SherlockMapActivity` is just an extension of `MapActivity` that add the capabilities of `ActionBarSherlock` to the `MapActivity`. However, it doesn't add an `onTap` method and `MapActivity` doesn't provide one either.

I guess what you are trying to detect a tap on the `MapView`. Several methods exists in order to do so. One of my favorite is to add a custom `Overlay` that does nothing but detects the tap. This `Overlay` has to be added at the first overlay in the `getOverlays()`'s `List`in order to have its `onTap` method called after all other `Overlay`s

Comment: Yep you are right, I miss read the code I found, there was an static Overlay on the middle on the Activity class and I thought, onTap was a MapActivity method...